# Fixed point iteration problem

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

So my $f(x)=0$ is:

$$x+e^x+e^{-3x}-4=0$$

Express $x$ as: $$x = 4-e^x-e^{-3x}$$

So my $g(x)$ is: $$4-e^x-e^{-3x}$$
$\varepsilon = 0.0001$

There is my graph, so my start point is $2$ for example ($x_0=2$)

[image]

Then I wrote a program which should find the root but I got $-\infty$.

[image]

Then I tried to use online programs to find root but they also returned $-\infty$.

**I think that the problem is in my $\boldsymbol{g(x)}$**

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you learned what properties guarantee your algorithm will converge? It is probably an issue of the initial point not being "close enough" to a solution, since it looks like your tangent line at $0$ will shoot you towards $-\infty$ instead of intersecting with the graph of your function

Comment: @Zim I  tried 0 ; 0.5 ; 1 and other initial points but useless... I i expected to see -0.445428 and 1.0632

Comment: Fixed point iteration won't work nicely with this function, because $|g'(x_{fix})|>1$. The roots you see from inspecting the graph of $g$ are: $\sim x\in \{ -0.4,1.3\}$, so a good hint that FPI won't work in this case, is plugging these into $|g'(x)|$, which gives something greater than 1, so both are repulsive fixed points of $g$. Use Newton's Method instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed-point iteration will not work if $|g'(x)|>1$ at the fixed-point, so a different $g$ must be chosen. You could consider instead the following functions for $g$:

$$\ln(4-x-e^{-3x}),~-\frac13\ln(4-x-e^x)$$

To find roots of $f$, other root-finding techniques, such as Newton's method or a bracketing method, could be tried instead. These are usually faster and have more guarantee of convergence.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was so elementary.I don't know how i forgot to check if my |g'(x)| > 1 I am so glad to you )))